# Find correct corresponding point to extend line

Tags: c++, geometry, line

I have two non parallel lines(XA and YB) which I need to extend to a curved line piece(PQ). The lines are made of arrays of (x,y) points. A is the last point in XA line and B is the last point in YB line. P and Q are the edge points of the curve.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now, I need to extend point A to P and point B to Q. Is there a way I can find the correct corresponding point of PQ curve so that A->P and B->Q and not A->Q and B->P, in the latter case the extended lines would intersect, that shouldn't happen.

Previously I had tried a simple boolean, but it was incorrect.

What I tried;

```
if(abs(A.x() - P.x()) < abs(B.x() - P.x())
   // extend A to P
   // extend B to Q
else
   // extend A to Q
   // extend B to P
```

The above wouldn't work for the image shown below, as then line A would be extended to point Q and line B to P (extension drawn in red).

[image: ![![enter image description here]

The solutions should look like the following;

[image] [image][image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this is being downvoted?

Comment: I can only speak in my name: I didn't downvote, but I was tempted. The question does't seem about programming, but about geometry. You don't show any code, you don't even mention the drawing library (standard c++ doesn't have a graphical interface). Also your question is confusing. `PQ` is one line, but in the end of the question you talk as there are two different lines `P` and `Q`. I have no idea what you mean there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I fixed a few mistakes in my code, hope it would help. In the code I have so far got to finding the points of the lines but am stuck at the extending part.

Comment: show some code then. But please make it as close as possible to a [MCVE], don't just dump the whole code.

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: Nothing new was added, question is still unclear.

Comment: And what are you going to do for the second picture case?

Comment: That's actually the problem, I need something to fit both scenarios..

Comment: But could you draw wanted solutions for some cases?

Comment: As shown, new segments just have ends `AEnd, P`  and `B_End, Q`. So what is problem?

Comment: I do not know which end of curve PQ is P or Q (I have the curve and can find the two end points, but don't know which point is which)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it:

Try one variant, check if the two segments intersect, and if they do then it's the other variant.

E.g. try `[AP], [BQ]`. Check if they intersect. If not then that is your config. Else then the config is `[AQ], [BP]`

To check if two line segments intersect is just math. Check this post from math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149622/finding-out-whether-two-line-segments-intersect-each-other